# Pass the inner fail/reject to the outer promise in jquery to avoid code duplication

Tags: jquery, node.js, typescript, deferred

I'm new to this deferred stuff but figured out a low. I'm still looking for a way to "save" the redundant `fail -> login` in the following code:

```
$.when(loginHandler.findLegacyUser(username, password))
    .done((doc:imports.ILegacyUser) => {
        $.when(loginHandler.migrateUser(doc, password))
            .done((doc:model.IUser) => {
                req.feedback.add("Your existing account was migrated successfully");
                req.session.username = doc.username;
                res.redirect('/members/');
            }).fail((err) => {
                login(req, res);
            });
    }).fail((err) => {
        login(req, res);
    });
```

What it does should be pretty clear from the naming I hope. So whenever the Migration fails we want to perform a nomal `login`. To migrate we first have to lookup a `LegacyUser`, if it's `null` the `migrateUser(doc, password)` will simply fail.

What I like to do is to passe the inner reject somehow to the outer promise.

Comment: By changing the outer `.done()` to `.then()`, you can exploit the filtering power of `.then()` and obviate the need for in the inner `fail()`. To achieve the required filtering effect, simply `return $.when(...).done(...)` from the inner function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understood what you mean, but I'm guessing you want only one fail handler, and the code should execute it regardless whether it's the outer or inner promise that is rejected.

In that case, you should provide your own promise and wrap the two calls in a method that will return this promise. Then you can attach resolved and rejected handlers to this promise.

Code:

```
var migrateWhenLegacyUser = function(username, password){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

     $.when(loginHandler.findLegacyUser(username, password))
         .done((doc:imports.ILegacyUser) => {
            $.when(loginHandler.migrateUser(doc, password))
                .done((doc:model.IUser) => {
                    deferred.resolve(doc);
                }).fail((err) => {
                    deferred.reject(req, err);
                }
            );
        }).fail((err) => {
            deferred.reject(req,err);
        }
    );   

    return deferred;
}

// usage example
migrateWhenLegacyUser("user","password").done((doc) => {
    req.feedback.add("Your existing account was migrated successfully");
    req.session.username = doc.username;
    res.redirect('/members/');
}).fail((req, err) => {
    login(req, res)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Q helped me with that. I would recommend everybody to prefer Q insted of jQuery at least in the node backend. Migrating is quite simple. Most works out of the box, and the differences are [well documented](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/Coming-from-jQuery)

```
Q.when(loginHandler.findLegacyUser(username, password))
        .then((legacyUser:imports.IBotUser) => {
            return Q.when(loginHandler.migrateUser(legacyUser, password));

        })
        .then((doc:userModel.IUser) => {
            req.feedback.add("Your existing account was migrated successfully");
            req.session.username = doc.username;
            res.send({success: true});
        })
        .fail((err) => {
            login(req, res);
        });
```

- Not tested yet but I will edit this answer if it has errors :)